# NullPointerException using Imagebutton in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

i am using a imagebutton in a fragment and am trying to open the drawerlayout with the image button
nah fragment and activity both have this button and in same places, so i have placed code in both places
Activity code probably does not work because fragment covers it

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

  private ImageButton mImageButton;

  public MainFragment() {

  }



  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);


    mImageButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.qpaper_menu_fragmain);   


    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MyActivity)getActivity()).openDrawer();
        }
    });             

    return view;
  }


}
```

imagebutton inside xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/qpaper_menu_fragmain"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button_blue"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description" />
```

Edit: sorry above it says view
i get NullPointerException with GetView
view gives error back in eclipse and doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
 View().findViewById(R.id.qpaper_menu_fragmain);
```

You cant find/reference a Views' Id from a class, you need to find/reference it from your inflated view which you already did.

**solution:**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
 mImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.qpaper_menu_fragmain);
```

Comment: umm sorry i did not understand that, because i already have all that written down
secondly sorry i was testing the stuff and it was supposed to be getView not View

Comment: @SahaabZahid you are still creating the View inside the onCreateView so getView will return null. Instead use the one I implemented above